# Remove field from a subclass of base abstract class Django

Tags: python, django, base-class

I am creating an application which needs a commenting system. I decided to use the comment app of Django, but needed to alter it a bit. First I do not want the user's email id to be mandatory and next I need an option to attach a file with the comment.

Thus I decided to subclass from BaseCommentAbstractModel. Now I need to override the user_email to be

```
user_email= models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

and add another field

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='data/files')
```

My code should look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.comments.models import  BaseCommentAbstractModel

class CommentWithFile(BaseCommentAbstractModel):
    '''This is a hack of the Comment model to remove email and add a filefield'''
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='data/files')
```

but this does not work. The user_email is still mandatory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the issue is to do with the model? `BaseCommentAbstractModel` doesn't even define `user_email`, that's only in the main `Comment` model - and it's defined as `blank=True` in any event.

I think it's more likely that you need to provide a custom form. The main `CommentDetailsForm` is not a modelform - it manually defines its fields, including a required `email` field. Sounds like you need to override that too.

Comment: Thanks, I will try creating a form. But lets assume that I inherit from Comment. Is there a possibility of changing it? Googling I found that in the .96 version there is a class called META and in that I can add remove_field = ('user_name',) but this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

[Since Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted) you have the ability to override abstract fields (i.e. fields of abstract base models).

> #### Field name “hiding” is not permitted
>
> [...]
>
> This restriction doesn’t apply to model fields inherited from an abstract model. Such fields may be overridden with another field or value, or be removed by setting `field_name = None`.

So the code you provided for the way you want your model to be is valid since Django 1.10.

Answer (score 1):

Just create custom form with a help of django generic views.

Models.py should look something like:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models
from django import forms

    class Comments(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=30)
        email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), blank=True, null=True)
        comment = models.TextField(_('Comment'))
        date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date'), auto_now_add=True)
        file = models.FileField(_('File'), upload_to='data/files')
        publish = models.BooleanField(_('Publish'))

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

Long answer: it depends.

You can for instance overwrite the **init** and save() methods to put in the field some default value (e.g. anonymous@example.com, an address that is fake by definition) and you'll then manage that case in code.